# 2 days overlap in my job - india

Tags: new-job, india, career-switch

Please help me. I have 2 days overlap in my job.

1st company - Date of exit 26th July 2018
2nd company - Date of Joining 25th July 2018.

I am unable to transfer my PF.

I requested me previous company to help me out but they said they cannot do anything and this can be done by new company.

So i requested new company and the HR tried her best and initiated the process and sent mail to management for approval.
Now, the legal team of my current company is saying that as per the policy of this company it is fine and let it be as is.

1. I do not have any employment issue in my current company which they have confirmed.
2. They will help me in rectifying PF either by giving decleration or withdrawing the amount.

I wanted to know this can be the issue with my future career turns. How should i be relaxed with this situation. What would be my future implications ?

Comment: This may get closed for asking legal advice, but I would recommend putting a location tag on your post.  In the US, this would be a non-issue, but the PF acronym is telling me this is not the US.

Comment: Most likely in India..but will wait for the OP to confirm.

Comment: I am from India. 

I am only concerned about my future jobs because every company does background verification.

What strategy I should keep in mind to proceed in my career. Or is this going to impact my career and I won't be able to change my job ??

I have so many things going in my mind.

Comment: If whatever the law or the rules in India changes when you get your future job (assuming you will stay on your current job for a while), who is going to care about **2 days** overlap? Or if your next job is outside India or remote, the overlap is nothing compared to the experience and skills you'll have.

Comment: thank you @scaaahu.

I am really worried and tensed from last 3 weeks as this mistake was unintensional and also i have contacted both of my companies and they know about the fact. 

I am actually thinking if I try to swtich then future organization which will be my 3rd company will have BGV check and then this might create an issue.

In that case, 
1. will they ask explanation or will terminate me ?
2. Shall I mention this issue upfront in my final HR discussion and justify myself. Will this work?
3. What kind of company I can target for my next job hunt?

Comment: what's a PF ????

Comment: Hi, welcome to The Workplace. I think your question would better fit in https://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is your issue is cleared ? I am also facing the same issue. Have you tried raising complaint I'm EPFO portal ?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to worry about I would say. If the the legal team of your current company is saying that as per their policy within their company it is fine and let it be as is, then let it be, move on.

Going forward in your career, no half-way competent future employer will be at all interested in this minuscule aspect of your career. They will be more interested in your skill-set, experience and temperament than this small issue of dates.

Hope this helps you to forget about this and focus instead on doing an excellent job in your current role, that will help your future career success the most. T

Comment: Thank you. the only thing worrying is in india every organisation does background verification check with previous employeer and if there is ovelap, they might take it as dual employment and can take action