Overlapping of relieving date with joining date
I have worked for 3 companies

1st company from Dec 8, 2016 to June 23, 2021
2nd company from June 24, 2021 to 0ct 21, 2021
3rd company from Oct 6, 2021 to April 16, 2024 (**Overlap)

I have given an interview 2 months back and got selected for an MNC. In background verification (BGV), I got the issue of overlapping 2nd company with 3rd company joining date with 18 days overlapping.
I gave the explanation on why there is a overlap - management of 2nd company changed and they considered the date mentioned in the exit portal as the last date (instead of the actual releasing date) and they even reply the same and I forwarded the same to new company. This is mostly an issue "on" the record.
Will there be any issues, and will they consider that and continue onboarding or will it become an issue for future companies as well? What I need to do now?

This question needs polishing. It's not particularly off topic but it's difficult to parse the information and can do with some rephrasing.

I tried editing the question to make it more readable, please feel free to revert in case it changed the facts/ meaning.

Thanks @SouravGhosh

Maybe, a similar question was asked before. The title was "2 days overlap in my job - india". The link is: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/128264/2-days-overlap-in-my-job-india


What I need to do now?

You have provided clarification, and given that you are not making something up, looks like they'll ignore the overlap and continue with the process.
However, this is not guaranteed, as there is no universal rule for background verification process (BGV), but in general (and as per my personal experience), an explanation with proper justification is usually accepted. If they disagree, there is nothing much that you can do - you can certainly challenge the "clerical" error on court, but that's an uphill battle - move on, maybe look for other opportunities elsewhere where they won't make a mountain out of a molehill.
